# Spring can not rolling back a declarative transaction

Tags: java, mysql, spring, transactions

I spent several hours on this issue, but got nothing. It's really makes me crazy! so I told myself, to the almighty stack overflow for help...

alright, this is my question. I throw a RuntimeException by myself in an add method on spring aop pointcut, what I want is the DB should rollback(no new record in table). I can see spring got the RuntimeException and invoked DataSourceTransactionManager.doRollback method in the below logs, but nothing happened, the data still being inserted into the table, transaction no rollback.

```
TRACE [main] org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute.rollbackOn(131) | Applying rules to determine whether transaction should rollback on java.lang.RuntimeException: error
TRACE [main] org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute.rollbackOn(148) | Winning rollback rule is: null
TRACE [main] org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.RuleBasedTransactionAttribute.rollbackOn(153) | No relevant rollback rule found: applying default rules
TRACE [main] org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCompletion(936) | Triggering beforeCompletion synchronization
DEBUG [main] org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(844) | Initiating transaction rollback
DEBUG [main] org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doRollback(282) | Rolling back JDBC transaction on Connection [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb, UserName=root@localhost, MySQL Connector Java]
TRACE [main] org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerAfterCompletion(965) | Triggering afterCompletion synchronization
TRACE [main] org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.clearSynchronization(331) | Clearing transaction synchronization
TRACE [main] org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager.doUnbindResource(243) | Removed value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@4a2af8f5] for key [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@43a4181c] from thread [main]
DEBUG [main] org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doCleanupAfterCompletion(325) | Releasing JDBC Connection [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306, UserName=root@localhost, MySQL Connector Java] after transaction
DEBUG [main] org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doReleaseConnection(327) | Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
```

BTW, I use MySQL DB, both default_storage_engine and table-engine value are InnoDB(which support transactions) and autocommit=1 by default, here is my spring transaction config here:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="root"/>
</bean> 

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<tx:advice id="serviceAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/>
            <tx:method name="*"/>
        </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="serviceAdvice" pointcut="execution(* com.service..*.*(..))"/>
</aop:config>
```

Java Code:

```
package com.dao.impl;

public void add(Event event) throws Exception {

    Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();

    PreparedStatement pstmt1 = conn
            .prepareStatement("insert into event (message) "
                    + "values ('test1')");
    pstmt1.executeUpdate();


    // pstmt2 execute a wrong SQL which will throw a exception 
    PreparedStatement pstmt2 = conn
            .prepareStatement("insert into event (wrong_column_name) "
                    + "values ('test2')");
    pstmt2.executeUpdate();
}
```

package com.service.impl;

```
public void add(Event event) {

        try {
            eventDao.add(event);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // using the RuntimeException to trigger a rollback
            throw new RuntimeException("error");    
        }
}
```

Thanks a lot for any help!

Comment: Can you share some code where you face described problem?

Comment: Hi, thanks for come in! I added some spring key code on it. Pls let me know if you want see more detail

Comment: Can you also share your EventDAO class?

Comment: Try using a following pointcut: within(com.service..*)

Comment: @bart.s sure! already update it, and also try the within(com.service..*) point cut, but it's can not work. I'm wondering why the log shows execute doRollback, but the 'test1' record still being inserted.

Comment: And what about "autocommit=1" that you mentioned? Maybe this is something messing here?

Comment: Hi, it's... a long story, do not care about it. I'm feeling terrible...

Comment: Well no it cannot and will not in this case... As you are messing around with a connection yourself, you should also manage the connection yourself. Either wrap the `DataSource` in a `TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy` or use a `JdbcTemplate` to have connection reuse, or use the `DataSourceUtils` to obtain a connection but don't do `getConnection` as you do now as that will create a connection outside the scope of spring... If you call this method a couple of times you will also have no more data access as your connection pool will be depleted.

Comment: @M.Deinum yea, you're right, thank you very much! I realized it too. And thank you bart.s , really thanks all you guys for help :)